# Beta distribution given one data

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian, beta-function

> Given a prior distribution $\mu$ ~ beta(a, b), what is the distribution of $\mu | X_{1}$, where $X_{1}$ is a Bernoulli random variable. What is $\mathbb{P}(X_{2} = 1 | X_{1} = 1)$?

I know from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Example) that knowing $X_{1} = 1$, I would change the distribution to $\mu$ ~ beta(a+1, b).

Then $\mathbb{P}(X_{2} = 1) = p$, which the the parameter of the Bernoulli random variable that follows the new distribution $\mu$ ~ beta(a+1, b). I was wondering if I am right so far and how to approach further beyond just providing a beta distribution as the result here.

Any hints/thoughts are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your posterior distribution given $X_1=1$ of $p \sim  \text{Beta}(a+1, b)$

You then get $\mathbb P(X_2=1 \mid X_1=1) = \mathbb E[p \mid X_1=1] = \dfrac{a+1}{a+1+b}$

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks a lot!